# sending mail with swift mailer (php) to gforge email gateway, equal signs (=) at the end of lines

Tags: php, smtp, swiftmailer, quoted-printable, gforge

Now, i have another problem with gForge.

I have a form in our intranet to create new trackers in our gforge system. We use Kohana and the Swift Mailer to send smtp emails.

This is what i get (i send the mail as bcc to myself):

```
Received: from 192.168.150.250 (192.168.150.250) by local
 (192.168.50.10) with Microsoft SMTP Server id 15.1.280.1; Wed, 16 Mar 2011
 08:51:40 +0100
Message-ID: <1300261898.4d80d7e6@192.168.150.250>
Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2011 08:51:38 +0100
Subject: Test_Issue Jieha (tracker-17)
From: <test@website.de>
To: <gforge-gateway@gforge.local>
BCC: <test@website.de>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Return-Path: test@website.de
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: local
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
MIME-Version: 1.0

priority:4
assignees: wollmannc
stardate: 03/16/2011
end date: 03/17/2011
Von user:
Name: Christian
email: meine@email.de

Bemerkung:
mein bemerkungstext
testinput: mein input
```

So everything looks fine. But Gforge is telling me:

```
Received: from local (192.168.200.19) by
 local (192.168.50.10) with Microsoft SMTP Server id
 15.1.280.1; Wed, 16 Mar 2011 08:51:42 +0100
Received: from gforge.local (centos5 [127.0.0.1])    by
 gforge.local (Postfix) with ESMTP id 5DBDED48174    for
 <test@website.de>; Wed, 16 Mar 2011 08:51:42 +0100 (CET)
Received: (from nobody@localhost)    by gforge.local
 (8.13.8/8.13.8/Submit) id p2G7pgvZ004723;    Wed, 16 Mar 2011 08:51:42 +0100
Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2011 08:51:42 +0100
From: <noreply@gforge.local>
Message-ID: <201103160751.p2GgvZ004723@gforge.local>
X-Authentication-Warning: gforge.local: nobody set sender to "GForge" <noreply@gforge.local> using -f
To: <test@website.de>
Reply-To: GForge <noreply@gforge.local>
Subject: =?utf-8?B?RmVobyIGJlaWgQmVhcmJlaXRlbiBkZXIgRW1haWw=?=
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ISO-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Return-Path: noreply@gforge.local
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: local
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
MIME-Version: 1.0

Ihre Email konnte nicht verarbeitet werden.
Die Anwendung sagte:

* Start Datum ist Erforderlich
* Schlieungs Datum ist Erforderlich
* Close Date must be > Open Date


Ihre Nachricht war:

priority:4
assignees: wollmannc
stardate: 03/16/2011
end d=
ate: 03/17/2011
Von user:
Name: Christian
email: meine@em=
ail.de

Bemerkung:
mein bemerkungstext
testinput: mei=
n input
```

It tells "the email could not be processed. The application says: a start date is required, a close date is required".

Note the equal signs at the end of some lines. I think that is the maximum line length of "quoted printable" or does the smtp also limit the lines? But why do i get the right mail through BCC? That should be the same mail that gforge gets, right?! Is Gforge doing something with incoming mails?

I'm confused :-( I hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be hitting [this bug in GForge](http://gforge.org/gf/project/as-help/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=6175) that prevents mails sent quoted-printable from being parsed correctly.

Your best bet is going to be telling Swift to not use quoted-printable, but I'm not sure how to do that.  (I actually want to do this in my own use of Swift...)

Comment: You can change the Content-Transfer-Encoding by doing this:

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject, $message, $html, 'utf-8');
  $message->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get8BitEncoding());

Answer (score 0):

GForge guy here.  FWIW, starting in [GForge 6.3](https://blog.gforgegroup.com/2013/09/03/what-to-expect-in-gforge-6-3/) you can create a custom email address for submitting new Tracker Items directly to a specific project and tracker.  No more adding special info to the subject line.

We've also made improvements to our back-end handling of email, to make it more compatible with the quirks of various email clients and exchangers.